# Can't telnet to Amazon SES server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I run...

```
telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25
```

And it says...

```
421 Timeout waiting for data from client
```

What am I missing?

I've validated a sender address and sent a test email, which arrived.

Comment: Looks fine for me, what do you think to get?

Comment: Shows how clueless I am!

Answer (score 1):

Because my SES service is sandboxed, I needed both the sender and recipient to be the verified email address.

From the top of the "Sending Statistics" page in the console...

> Your Amazon SES account has "sandbox" access in region US East (N.
>   Virginia). With sandbox access you can only send email to the Amazon
>   SES mailbox simulator and to email addresses or domains that you have
>   verified. To be moved out of the sandbox, please request a sending
>   limit increase.

Answer (score 0):

That works fine. You should probably check if outgoing traffic to port 25 is blocked in your network environment. Many organizations block that outgoing traffic for security reasons.

You can check that port with `nmap`. Here's what it looks like from a network where traffic is permitted:

```
$ nmap email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -p 25 | grep '25/tcp'
25/tcp open  smtp
```

And from a network where it is not permitted:

```
$ nmap email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -p 25 | grep '25/tcp'
25/tcp filtered smtp
```

Comment: How could it be blocked if I'm able to connect to the mail server?

Comment: Ehm. Communication breakdown. The way the question is phrased, I though you got timeout from `telnet`, not further down the process.